# How to send email with organization email

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I want to send Email with this host "mail.rayatak.ir" .When I use below code ,that works well with host "smtp.gmail.com", but doesn't work with host "mail.rayatak.ir"

```
            var emailFrom = "test@rayatak.ir";
            var emailFromPassword = "********";
            var emailAddress = "mail.rayatak.ir";
            int emailPort = 587;
            bool enableSsl = false;

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();

            MailboxAddress from = new MailboxAddress("کاوانو",emailFrom);
            message.From.Add(from);

            MailboxAddress to = new MailboxAddress("soheila tarighi", email);
            message.To.Add(to);

            message.Subject = _subject;
            BodyBuilder bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
            //bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = _subject;
            bodyBuilder.TextBody = htmlMessage;
            message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();
            MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient();
            client.Connect(emailAddress, emailPort, enableSsl);
            client.Authenticate(emailFrom,emailFromPassword);
            client.Send(message);
            client.Disconnect(true);
            client.Dispose();
            return true;
```

```
Error Message:An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.

The SSL certificate presented by the server is not trusted by the system for one or more of the following reasons:
1. The server is using a self-signed certificate which cannot be verified.
2. The local system is missing a Root or Intermediate certificate needed to verify the server's certificate.
3. The certificate presented by the server is expired or invalid.

See https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#InvalidSslCertificate for possible solutions.
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 1: Updated by answer after realizing the mail server supports StartTLS. My previous answer works but it would ultimately disable TLS.**

I'm having a hard time reading the C# documentation, but based on the errors, it appears that there is a conflict with the SSL certificate being presented by the server.

This can be verified with
(1) `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect mail.rayatak.ir:587`:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, ST = TX, L = Houston, O = "cPanel, Inc.", CN = "cPanel, Inc. Certification Authority"
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = linux4.centraldnserver.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=linux4.centraldnserver.com
   i:/C=US/ST=TX/L=Houston/O=cPanel, Inc./CN=cPanel, Inc. Certification Authority
 1 s:/C=US/ST=TX/L=Houston/O=cPanel, Inc./CN=cPanel, Inc. Certification Authority
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=linux4.centraldnserver.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=TX/L=Houston/O=cPanel, Inc./CN=cPanel, Inc. Certification Authority
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 5430 bytes and written 468 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 964B697E5F8A7766FA5D19CD237DADEC57D4BE2A6E00E603D9B1FC4D364F0BA5
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: E12497F3E9C4AACAA10FAF2374DBC6D098898F2E5A3B538BB38750F9E938863DD1A253ABE27AB3B6605ABCB992C84E68
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1567999858
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

And by inspecting the SAN extensions (2) `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect mail.rayatak.ir:587 | openssl x509 -text -noout | grep DNS:`:

```
DNS:linux4.centraldnserver.com, DNS:www.linux4.centraldnserver.com
```

Notice that the canonical name in the certificate (`CN=linux4.centraldnserver.com`) does not match the domain name you are using `mail.rayatak.ir` for the connection and the SAN extension does not include `mail.rayatak.ir`.

Fix:

```
client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s,c,h,e) => true;
client.Connect(emailAddress, emailPort, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls)
```

1. Bypass certificate checks (not recommended though, check this [link](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#InvalidSslCertificate)).
2. Explicitly instruct your code to use StartTLS.